# Can't override view.View method with Android Studio

Tags: android, view, overriding, android-studio, android-scrollview

I'm extending ScrollView with this ObservableScrollView class (copyright Roman Nurik) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

 /**
 * A custom ScrollView that can accept a scroll listener.
 */
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDrawVerticalScrollBar(Canvas canvas, Drawable scrollBar, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        this.getOverlay().add(scrollBar);
        super.onDrawVerticalScrollBar(canvas, scrollBar, l, t, r, b);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onScrollChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
    }

    public void setCallbacks(Callbacks listener) {
        mCallbacks = listener;
    }

    public static interface Callbacks {
        public void onScrollChanged();
    }

}
```

Problem is, Android Studio (0.2.2) says it can't find the OnDrawVerticalScrollBar method that I want to override. No problem with onScrollChanged though.

In my manifest : minSdkVersion="7" and targetSdkVersion="18"
I checked [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java?av=f) and Android 2.1 did have this method...

I'm aware the overlay stuff is only going to work with 4.3 but I'll change it later, this is just temporary.

I only have Java 1.6 installed and all my settings say I'm using Java 6.

Hope you can help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, turns out onDrawVerticalScrollBar is annotated with @Hide in the source file, and onDrawScrollbars is a final method. So it's not possible.